# Approximation of integral as integral range tends to 0

Tags: integration, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I would like to approximate $\int_{0}^{x}t^{-2}e^{t}\mathrm{d}t$ (maybe find the first two terms) as $x\rightarrow0$. I can't seem to do it by "divide and conquer" or any method. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: That integral is $+\infty$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: $\int t^n e^t\, dt$ by parts gives $\int t^{n-1} e^t\, dt$ , then reverse the equation and make $t^{-2} \rightarrow t^{-1} \rightarrow t^0$

Comment: sorry what do you mean by reverse the equation?

Comment: The integral doesn't exist for any $x$.  It doesn't make sense to ask about approximating it.